# HTML\javascript показать файл с другого сайта

Tags: javascript, html, django

Мой вебсайт использует https, и есть такая проблема, что мне нужно показать в браузере клиента pdf\jpeg\htm файл с другого сайта (http). Браузеры не позволяют сделать это из соображений безопасности (пробовал object, iframe и т.д - всё бестолку). Скачивать файлы не комильфо - этих файлов порядка 6 тысяч.  Придумал такой обход - можно сначала скачать файл на сервере по ссылке, а потом отдать его как ответ клиенту. Есть ли какой-либо способ показать файл из ответа сервера?
Ну или подскажите способ, как можно показать pdf\jpeg\htm файл на https с http сайта или какой нибудь обходной путь. Любые предложения - javascript, html, js библиотеки. Мой сервер использует python django, хостинг - Heroku

Comment: Возможно вас заинтересует Simple PHP Proxy - http://benalman.com/projects/php-simple-proxy/

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас пробую https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/ - вот это. Нашел на просторах stackoverflow. Если не сработает, то попробую ваше решение