# api музыкального сайта

Tags: javascript, php, api

Есть ли такого Сервис который дает API чтобы получить новую музыку и сохранять их на сервере, в этом деле новичок много не знаю.
Посмотрел что вконтакте дает API, но не понял как сохранять музыку на свой сервер
хочу сделать на языке php, jquery.

Comment: А __авторские права__ или __разрешение от звукозаписывающей компании__ у вас есть, чтобы чужую музыку хранить на своем сервере и давать ее прослушивать кому угодно?

Comment: Если где-то есть АПИ, о котором идёт речь, то за соблюдение авторских прав скорее отвечает тот, кто даёт это АПИ, чем тот, кто этим пользуется.

Answer (score 0):

Используя [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Blob), можно загрузить файл с одного сервера и отправить на другой. Подобное обсуждалось [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/580715/html-javascript-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D1%81-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0).